# Preventing units from being "broken" to the next line

Tags: formatting, academic-writing, software, tools, scientific-publishing

I'm having trouble with keeping "units" on the same line, or together. For example, g C m<sup>-2</sup> (grams of carbon per square meter) often gets broken between the "-" and "2". I realize it's possible to use non-breaking spaces, but this doesn't help in this situation because there aren't spaces between "-" and "2". Any ideas?

I'm using Microsoft Word 2007 on a PC (and mac). 
Apologies if this is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Sorry about the weird tagging accident there.  Not sure how that happened, but fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need a nonbreaking hyphen. It'll keep the characters before and after it from breaking across lines. From [Butterick's Practical Typography](http://practicaltypography.com/nonbreaking-hyphens.html):

> Your word proces­sor as­sumes that any hy­phen marks a safe place to flow the text onto a new line or page. Sim­i­lar to the non­break­ing space, the non­break­ing hy­phen looks iden­ti­cal to a hy­phen but will not be used as a place for a line break or page break.

[In Word 2007](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-hyphen-HA010096395.aspx#BM2) for Windows, Press CTRL+SHIFT+HYPHEN. On Word for Mac 2010, press command-shift-dash or Insert > Symbol > Advanced Symbol.

Comment: Ahh! I feel silly now, I wasn't even thinking of the "minus sign" as a hyphen...

Comment: That works in Word 2003 and 2013 for Windows also.  Just to avoid the inevitable question, the same problem and same solution applies if the -2 is superscripted.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited my units to superscripts, as it should be.